# C++ Explicit Instantiation while still allowing implicit Instantiation of additional types?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a project that is essentially all templated.  However, I know for a fact that 99% of my users will ONLY ever need a specific subset of the possible instantiations.

For example, I have a `Camera` class which 99% of my users will only ever instantiate as one of the following:

```
Camera<float,Mono>
Camera<float,RGB>
Camera<double,Mono>
Camera<double,RGB>
```

But, there are some niche users who will need to use something like:

```
Camera<float, Spectrum<N>>
```

where `N` is only know for the user's specific program.

In the past, I have used explicit instantiation where I have known the specific subset of instantiations I'd want, which dramatically speeds up compilation time and allowed me to separate implementation from the header files.  (I am a big fan of having declaration only header files for readability purposes).

However here, because I want that flexibility, I've kept things as header-only templates.

Is it possible to provide explicit instantiations for the known cases to help speed up compile time, while still allowing users to specify their own implicit instantiations if absolutely needed?

Another alternative I'm thinking of is going fully to explicit instantiation (moving all definitions into the `.cpp` files) and then explicit instantiating:

```
Camera<float, Spectrum<SPECTRAL_BIN_COUNT>
```

where `SPECTRAL_BIN_COUNT` can be set via a `#define`.  (And if not set, will simply default to some value).

My concern with the latter is that in the future I may want some additional flexibility, so it'd be desirable to be totally flexible with template instantiations.

Comment: Something like this perhaps. Make three files: `camera.h` with just the declarations, `camera_impl.h` with implementation, and `camera.cpp` with explicit instantiations. Source files that only need predefined instantiations can only include `camera.h`. Files that need custom instantiations would additionally include `camera_impl.h`

Comment: Thanks so much for this additional input!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing special you have to take care of. You just define everything in the header as usual and include declarations for the explicit instantiations. Then in your `.cpp` you provide definitions for these instantiations. Then all users have all definitions available for implicit instantiations but won't implicitly instantiate the explicitly instantiated specializations.

In the header after the class template definition (and member definitions) add the explicit instantiation declarations:

```
extern template Camera<float,Mono>;
extern template Camera<float,RGB>;
extern template Camera<double,Mono>;
extern template Camera<double,RGB>;
```

and in your library `.cpp`, after including the header, add the explicit instantiation definitions:

```
template Camera<float,Mono>;
template Camera<float,RGB>;
template Camera<double,Mono>;
template Camera<double,RGB>;
```

Also make sure that you don't declare the member functions as `inline`, i.e. define them out-of-class and don't add the `inline` specifier. Otherwise the explicit instantiation declaration will not prevent implicit instantiation.